# QML/C++ Master/Detail ComboBox/Listview

Tags: qml, qtquick2, master-detail, qtquickcontrols2

On Qt 5.7, Quick Controls 2.0, I have a master ComboBox with a slave ListView. How can the slave change when the user changes the ComboBox selection?

For exemple:

Imagine that I have a list of persons, and every person has a list of cars:

- Person1 - car1, car2, car3
- Person2 - car4
- Person3 - car5, car6, car7, car8
- Person4 - car9, car10
  ...

The persons must appears on ComboBox and when the users selects a person, the Listview must show person's cars.

I've tried this, but the carsRole is never called on data member, so the ListView doesn't show anything.

QML:

```
ComboBox {
    textRole: "name"
    model: personsModel
}
ListView {
    model: personsModel.cars
}
```

C++

```
enum PersonsRoles {
    nameRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
    carsRole
};

QVariant PersonsModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    int row = index.row();
    if ((row < 0) || (row >= _persons.size())) {
        return QVariant();
    }
    switch (role) {
    case nameRole:
        return _persons.at(row);
    case carsRole: {        
        return QVariant::fromValue(new CarsModel(row));
    }
    }
    return QVariant();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> PersonsModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[nameRole] = "name";
    roles[carsRole] = "cars";
    return roles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expose the roles enum to QML, you can call [`QAbstractItemModel::data()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data), which is marked as [`Q_INVOKABLE`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_INVOKABLE) since Qt 5.5:

C++:

```
enum PersonsRoles {
    nameRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
    carsRole
};
Q_ENUM(PersonsRoles)
```

QML:

```
ComboBox {
    id: comboBox
    textRole: "name"
    model: personsModel
}

ListView {
    model: personsModel.data(personsModel.index(comboBox.currentIndex, 0), PersonsModel.carsRole)
}
```

If `PersonsModel` is already registered as a QML type and you create the instance in QML, this will already work. If `personsModel` is a context property, you'll have to register `PersonsModel` to QML, for example:

```
qmlRegisterUncreatableType("foo.bar", 1, 0, "PersonsModel", "PersonsModel is a context property"):
```

And then `import foo.bar 1.0` in QML.